# Nodejs: Avoid duplication code in controllers and services

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have multiple controllers and services.
Some files are have the same code like this:

Banner controller:

```
const status = async (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const params: any = req.params;

  try {
    const response = await BannerService.status(params.id);

    if (!response.data) {
      return next(new RequestError(0))
    }

    return next(new RequestError(2))
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new RequestError(1))
  }
};
```

Admin controller:

```
const status = async (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const params: any = req.params;

  try {
    const response = await AdminService.status(params.id);

    if (!response.data) {
      return next(new RequestError(0))
    }

    return next(new RequestError(2))
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new RequestError(1))
  }
};
```

So, my question: Is this way correct and standard?

Or better way is I create a global function for handle it like this:

```
const statusController = (serviceFn) => {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const params: any = req.params;

    try {
      const response = await serviceFn(params.id);

      if (!response.data) {
        return next(new RequestError(0))
      }

      return next(new RequestError(2))
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new RequestError(1))
    }
  };
};

const adminStatus = statusController(AdminService.status);
const bannerStatus = statusController(BannerService.status);
```

Comment: IMO option two is the way to go. Don't Repeat Yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a handler that handles it. Create an abstract class and implement it for each controller:

```
class abstract BaseHandler < TResponse > {
  abstract getData(): TResponse;
  getStatus() {
    try {
      const response = await serviceFn(params.id);

      if (!response.data) {
        return next(new RequestError(0))
      }

      return next(new RequestError(2))
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new RequestError(1))
    }
  };
}
```

Then implement it for each controller. Disclaimer this is just pseudocode, and it won't work.

Comment: Thank you. if one service need call a function after result, how can I manage it?

Comment: Would you be so gentle to mark the question as resolved @MHHH ? Usually, you do it with promises or rxjs observable.  But observable are way more flexible. I give you an observable example: `of(first$).pipe(switchMap(result => second$).subscribe`